# How can I properly get the height of a UIViewController's subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I can't understand this, should be an easy question tho.
I have a ViewController in a navigation controller. 2 views more or less. Top view is a tableview that takes up 95% of the view, and has top/leading/trailing. 2nd view is a fixed 44 height UIView at the bottom, with leading/trailing/bottom... and vertical spacing to tableView.
On viewDidLoad, I print out the CGRect's for the tableview, the fixed 44 height uiview, and the main view. I get this...

```
tableViewRect: {{0, 64}, {600, 492}} 
fixedHeightViewRect: {{0, 556}, {600, 44}} 
self.view: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
```

However, I look at it on my device and the fixed 44 height view is CLEARLY at the very bottom of my phone.
Something is wonky here. If the entire height of the display is 667, yet the fixedHeightView is starting at 556 and is 44 high, therefore its on screen vertically between 556 and 600... how am I able to see it at the very bottom of my screen, a screen which is 667 in height.
I would expect fixedHeight would start at Y: 623 (going to 667). I would then in turn expect the height of my tableView to be 559.
However, I'm not getting this. Why is that?

Comment: Look at those value in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. They should be more accurate then.

Comment: The default view size in the storyboard is 600 x 600.  Your view hasn't been  been laid out yet in `viewDidLoad` so they still have the frames they had in the storyboard.